# Set animation for ViewSwitcher programmatically

Tags: android, android-animation, viewswitcher

I set the animation in the layout like this:

```
<ViewSwitcher
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
    android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right" >
```

How can I do the same programmatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read the documentation for the `ViewSwitcher` class, it has two methods for setting the in/out animation:

```
// load the two animations  
Animation animIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
Animation animOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
// set them on the ViewSwitcher
vs.setInAnimation(animIn);
vs.setOutAnimation(animOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
viewswitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in));
viewswitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_out));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the step of loading the animation with `AnimationUtils` and instead pass the anim resource directly:

```
switcher.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
switcher.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```